# getting a list as a result of a function instead of one value PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

So, I am very new with SQL functions. I am trying to get average of all shortest distances, but I am getting only those distances instead. Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sd_avgDistance(entry1 geometry,entry2 geometry) 
RETURNS FLOAT AS $$
SELECT avg(st_distance(entry1,entry2))
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Your function takes two geometries and returns the distance between them.  It is unclear what you really want to do.  The `avg()` isn't doing anything.

Comment: Oh, *a bad word*! I saw this problem all along but your comment made it more clear. So, to get average of all shortest distances, I need to do function inside a function, right?